# Saving custom attribute field in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I've written some code that adds an extra text field to the backend of product attributes.

Ik hooked my code on the `woocommerce_before_edit_attribute_fields`hook like this:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_edit_attribute_fields', array($this, 'woocommerce_attribute_extra_label_textfield'), 10, 0 );

 function woocommerce_attribute_extra_label_textfield() {
        ?>
        <tr class="form-field">
            <th valign="top" scope="row">
                <label for="display"><?php _e('Label tekst', ''); ?></label>
            </th>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="attribute_label_name" id="attribute_label_name">
                <p class="description"><?php _e('Dit veld overschrijft de benaming van het eigenschap. Wordt weergegeven op de productdetail pagina.', ''); ?> </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php
    }
?>
```

The result shows my field in the options of the attribute settings page:

[image]

However, when saving, the field is not yet stored in the database.

I have made a few attempts to search for a saving process, and I mostly end up with my hook `woocommerce_before_edit_attribute_fields`, which according to some examples should already save with this hook.

I also cannot find a proper hook that processes the attribute field storage. Does anyone know a hook for this or am I missing something in my existing code?

Comment: this answers your question https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/371083/add-custom-field-to-woocommerce-add-new-attribute-edit-page

Comment: @7uc1f3r thanks! I will look into this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the **hook `woocommerce_admin_process_product_object`** to handle your custom product data.

```
add_action('woocommerce_admin_process_product_object', 'save_my_custom_product_fields');

function save_my_custom_product_fields( $product ) {
    
    if ( isset( $_REQUEST['attribute_label_name'] ) ) {
        $product->add_meta_data( 'attribute_label_name', $_REQUEST['attribute_label_name'], true );
    }
    
}
```